# How can access to NFS datas in GitlabCi job?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In a gitlabCI job, I would like to recover data stored on an NFS to launch my automatic tests (large SQLite file for example).

As each job is launched in a docker container, how do you mount a volume to my NFS when the job starts?
Nothing found on the internet, I'm the only one to meet this problem or it's a bad practice?

Comment: Having the mount done by the [runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#example-2-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) itself is a acceptable solution for you ?

Comment: even if the volume is mounted on the runner, can I access it from the docker? does it not require privileged mode?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a setup with NFS to test but reading the documentation, the volume will be available in container started from `images:` but also (since runner version 11.11) in container started from `services:` without privileged mode. One thing, you need to use either `docker`, `docker-windows`, `docker-ssh`, `docker+machine` or `docker-ssh+machine` executor type.